# Combine sub lists of different lists into a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large number of lists which each consist of many sub lists. Each list contains a sub-list, where each sub-list will have with the same name and number of observations in different lists.

Here's a simple example of data:

```
score <- list(Bob = list(c('1'), ('0')), Jane = list(c('1'), ('2'), ('4'), ('2')))
comments <- list(Bob = list(c('AAA'), ('BBB')), Jane = list(c('ZZZ'), ('XXX'), ('YYY'), ('QQQ')))
```

I am looking to create a list of data frames that combines the sub-lists together and preserves the names.

```
my.list.Bob
score   comments  
1    AAA  
0    BBB

my.list.Jane  
score   comments  
1    ZZZ  
2    XXX  
4    YYY  
2    QQQ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way for you. If you have all lists in your global environment, you can do the following. First, you create a list with all lists you have. Then, you use `transpose()` that allows you to create a list for each person (e.g., a list for Bob with score and comments). In each list, you have comments and score as nested lists in this case. You want to unlist them in each list. For that reason, you can use `rapply2()` by rawr. Finally, you create a data frame for each list.

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(rawr) #devtools::install_github('raredd/rawr')

score <- list(Bob = list(c('1'), ('0')), Jane = list(c('1'), ('2'), ('4'), ('2')))
comments <- list(Bob = list(c('AAA'), ('BBB')), Jane = list(c('ZZZ'), ('XXX'), ('YYY'), ('QQQ')))

# Get all objects in the global environment and create a list.
mylist <- mget(ls(pattern =  ".*"))

purrr::transpose(mylist) %>%
rapply2(unlist, classes = "list") %>%
lapply(as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

$Bob
  comments score
1      AAA     1
2      BBB     0

$Jane
  comments score
1      ZZZ     1
2      XXX     2
3      YYY     4
4      QQQ     2
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). The idea is to use `map2` loop through each element from two lists, use `map_dfr` and `as_data_frame` to create data frame, and then use `bind_cols` to combine each data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

map2(score, comments, function(x, y){
  X <- map_dfr(x, as_data_frame)
  Y <- map_dfr(y, as_data_frame)
  dat <- bind_cols(X, Y) %>%
    set_names(c("score", "comments"))
})
# $Bob
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   score comments
#   <chr> <chr>   
# 1 1     AAA     
# 2 0     BBB     
# 
# $Jane
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   score comments
#   <chr> <chr>   
# 1 1     ZZZ     
# 2 2     XXX     
# 3 4     YYY     
# 4 2     QQQ
```